# MVC3 Database tutorials?

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm looking for some good tutorials involving ASP.NET MVC 3 and SQL Server databases. EF Code First (a la the tutorials on the ASP.net site) seems a little immature at this point so I'm looking for alternatives. My project is in C# but I also know VB so if I have to translate it's no big deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well you could use linq to sql, tutorials->

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx#linqtosql_topic28

steve sanderson has a great book regarding asp net framework http://blog.stevensanderson.com/category/sql/
with a real app developed including data management...

additionally -you could request a 30 day free trial -

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro

www.pluralsight.com offer a great set of tutorials for asp.net mvc3

give me more details and I will provide you with more links brgds.